# How to calculate and display percentages from a binary dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to create a table, where I calculate the percentages of applicants in different stages of a recruitment process. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  CandidateType     Step   Amount
        <fctr>      <chr>   <dbl>
1     External   Hiring       304
2     Internal   Hiring       164
3     External   Interview    950
4     Internal   Interview    512
5     External   Application 8726
6     Internal   Application  828
```

I need to add a column that calculates the percentages of applications that result in an interview, and the percentages of applications that ends up as hirings for each Group (internal and external applicants). It should look something like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  CandidateType     Step   Amount     Pct
        <fctr>      <chr>   <dbl>    <chr>
1     External   Hiring       304   3.48 %
2     Internal   Hiring       164  19.81 %
3     External   Interview    950  10.89 %
4     Internal   Interview    512  61.84 %
5     External   Application 8726 100.00 %
6     Internal   Application  828 100.00 %
```

I've tried solving the problem using the following code, but with no luck:

```
recruitmentDFinternal <- recruitmentDF %>% 
  filter(CandidateType == "Internal") %>% 
  percent((Amount) / Amount[3])
```

The idea here was to use the `percent` function from the `scales` package, and create two separate data frames from each type of candidate, to ultimately do a `bind_rows` to piece them back together, but I had no luck getting the `percent` function to work. Does anyone have a solution for this problem? I need the Pct column to contain a %-symbol at the end of the percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group your `tibble` by `CandidateType` and divide the `Amount` of every row by the maximum `Amount`:

```
recruitmentDF %>% 
  group_by(CandidateType) %>% 
  mutate(Pct = scales::percent(Amount / max(Amount)))
```

This returns:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   CandidateType [2]
  CandidateType Step        Amount Pct   
  <fct>         <fct>        <int> <chr> 
1 External      Hiring         304 3.5%  
2 Internal      Hiring         164 19.8% 
3 External      Interview      950 10.9% 
4 Internal      Interview      512 61.8% 
5 External      Application   8726 100.0%
6 Internal      Application    828 100.0%
```

Comment: Very cool! Thank you so much! - I would upvote, but I haven't got enough reputation yet, sorry :-(